# Invoke jar from C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface, 64-bit

I am trying to call a .jar file from native code. It seems no matter what I try, I always get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failed setting boot class path.
```

I have already tried several jars to see if it was some problem with the application itself, and I have tried to unpack the jar and load the main class directly, but nothing seems to work. I am using the JDK 21 with a jar that has been validated to work.

The code is below:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class JavaVMExecutor {
private:
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    jclass mainClass;
    jmethodID mainMethod;

public:
    JavaVMExecutor(const std::string& classpath) {
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
        JavaVMOption options[1];
        std::string classPathOption = "-Djava.class.path=" + classpath;
        options[0].optionString = const_cast<char*>(classPathOption.c_str());

        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;
        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

        // !!! THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS !!!
        JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
        mainClass = env->FindClass("MainClassName");
        mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    }

    void invoke() {
        jstring arg = env->NewStringUTF("");
        jobjectArray args = env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), arg);
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, mainMethod, args);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(arg);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(args);
    }

    void kill() {
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    }

    ~JavaVMExecutor() {
        kill();
    }
};

int main() {
    JavaVMExecutor executor("C:\\Users\\InfiniPLEX\\Desktop\\Newfolder\\mcaselector-2.3\\net\\querz\\mcaselector\\Main.class");
    executor.invoke();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code dies in the line  starting in "JNI_CreateJavaVM" or in the line below? If the first case is true, then the issue is not with your Jar file. The method is just not able to find the RTL because it does not have a BootClassPath (the path to the RTL).

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing much about how JNI works, I have tried to set the java bootclass path and the runtime directory, neither of which resolved the problem. Could you provide an example of how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: My last exposure to JNI is ages ago and I am far from being sure that my knowledge about the details is still valid … – nevertheless, can you add the code showing your attempts to set the BootClassPath to your question? And did you set JAVA_HOME correctly (just another idea)?

Comment: Is "MainClassName" really the class you're trying to invoke? Judging from your load path, you actually wanted `net/querz/mcaselector/Main`. In which case the classpath entry should stop at "mcaselector-2.3".

Comment: The class path is definitely wrong. What you have specified is the main class not the class path. A class path is a JAR file or a directory if class files.

Comment: Maybe this sample will give you some hints: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo050